# cacti send alert once nginx cannot be accessed

Tags: nginx, cacti

I already enabled graph on Nginx client stat and Nginx Socket stat, threshold plugin also installed, and they are working fine.
I would like to know how can I get alert once users can't access nginx? and how can I get the response time graph of nginx.
thanks a lot.